# Selenium screenshots are chopped off

Tags: python, html, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to take screenshots of different elements (on different sections) of a long page. The first screenshot I take is near the top of the page and comes out not chopped off:

[image]

However, once selenium has to scroll to take a screenshot of an element, the screenshot comes out chopped off:

[image]

I'm pretty sure this is happening because selenium isn't scrolling far enough for the entire element to be exposed, and thus takes a screenshot that comes out incomplete – but I don't know how to solve the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Below is my code so far (screen-shotting the element happens in the last few lines of code):

```
from time import sleep
from os import chdir
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.service import Service
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager

option = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
option.add_experimental_option("excludeSwitches", ["enable-automation"])
option.add_experimental_option('useAutomationExtension', False)
option.add_argument("--disable-infobars")
option.add_argument("start-maximized")
option.add_argument("--disable-extensions")
option.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
option.add_experimental_option("prefs", { 
    "profile.default_content_setting_values.notifications": 2 
})

driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=Service(ChromeDriverManager().install()),options=option)
driver.get("https://www.reddit.com/r/AskReddit/")

#Show top reddit posts on the subreddit
topButton = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/a[3]")))
topButton.click()

#Topic
topic = WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[4]/div[1]/div[4]/div[2]')))
topic.click()
sleep(1)
topicText = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div/div[3]/div[1]/div/h1').text
topicPicture = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/div')
chdir(r'C:\Users\jack_l\Documents\PLAYING_WITH_REDDIT\currentVideo')
topicPicture.screenshot('topic.png')

#Comments
comment = ''
verified = 0
counter4 = 0

while(verified <= 10):
    try:
        comment = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div[2]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[5]/div/div/div/div['+str(counter4)+']')
    except Exception:
        counter4 = counter4+1
    else:
        if 'level 1' in comment.text:
            comment.screenshot('comment '+str(verified)+'.png')
            verified = verified + 1
        counter4 = counter4+1
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add this line in the try block after the definition of `comment`. What it does is simply to scroll down in such a way that the webelement `comment` is at the center of the page. This way it takes a full screenshot

```
try:
    comment = driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '...')
    driver.execute_script('arguments[0].scrollIntoView({block: "center"});', comment)
except:
    ...
```